# (swift2) Variable is not changing within if statement

Tags: swift, swift2

The problem I am facing ishat i am unable to update the variable lin. I have tried multipleimes a f:) . To get to the relevode quick 2nd line in the code is where the variable is identified and then if u scroll to bottom of the code that is where the variable is suppose to change but does not

```
let menable = UITabletgView()
let arfSorces:[String] = ["C"]




public func runMenu(){
    if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow{

        dimming.frame = window.frame
        dimming.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 0.5087)

        dimming.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("eefefef")))

        let height: CGFloat = 100000
        let y = window.frame.height - height + height
        menuTable.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.height, height: height)

        window.addSubview(dimming)
        window.addSubview(mee)

       eView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("c", forIndexPath: indexPath)as UITableViewCell
    e.textLabel?.text = ars[indexPath.item]
    return e
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50000
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    func RunLink(){
        if let v = c{
          98bdfe8daf6543d92"
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the if statement you declare a brand-new variable link1 that only exists inside that if statement. Change

```
if arrayOfSorces[indexPath.item] == arrayOfSorces[0]{
    var link1 = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?sources=bbc-news&apiKey=a9ea5ee627044bd98bdfe8daf6543d92"
    RunLink()
}
```

To

```
if arrayOfSorces[indexPath.item] == arrayOfSorces[0]{
   link1 = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?sources=bbc-news&apiKey=a9ea5ee627044bd98bdfe8daf6543d92"
    RunLink()
}
```

(Get rid of the `var`. That creates a new variable rather than changing the value that's in the existing variable.)

Comment: The idea of variables and scope is *critical* to understanding modern programming, and one you should study intensely until you really understand it.